# name 'main_window' is not defined

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

```
from tkinter import *

def create_main_window():
    global main_window
    main_window = Toplevel()
    main_window.update()

entrance_window = Tk()
first_text_label = Label(entrance_window, text="you are in:").grid(row=0, column=0)
place_entry = Entry(entrance_window).grid(row=0, column=1)

submit_button = Button(entrance_window, text="Submit", command=create_main_window).grid(row=1, column=0, columnspan=2)
Label(main_window, text=f"{place_entry}").pack()
entrance_window.mainloop()
```

the program should open a new window with the text from the entry box from the first window but it either shows `None` if I write

```
Label(main_window, text=f"{place_entry}").pack()
```

in the create_main_window or it gives me an error saying that main_window is not defined if I write it after the button code.

Can someone help with this?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```py
from tkinter import *


def create_main_window():
    global main_window
    main_window = Toplevel(main_window)
    label = Label(main_window, text=f"{place_entry.get()}")
    label.pack()
    # main_window.update() # This is useless


entrance_window = Tk()

first_text_label = Label(entrance_window, text="You are in:")
first_text_label.grid(row=0, column=0)

place_entry = Entry(entrance_window)
place_entry.grid(row=0, column=1)

submit_button = Button(entrance_window, text="Submit", command=create_main_window)
submit_button.grid(row=1, column=0, columnspan=2)
entrance_window.mainloop()
```

I moved the label creation inside `create_main_window`. Also please note that using `var = a().b()`, saves what ever `b()` returns inside `var`. That is why when you use `var = Entry(...).pack(...)`, `var` is always `None`.

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are trying to add a Label to an object that doesn't exist. Move the Label function to the create_main_window() function, like below:

```
from tkinter import *

def create_main_window():
    global main_window, entrance_window
    main_window = Toplevel()
    place_entry = Entry(entrance_window).grid(row=0, column=1)
    Label(main_window, text=f"{place_entry}").pack()
    main_window.update()

entrance_window = Tk()
first_text_label = Label(entrance_window, text="you are in:").grid(row=0, column=0)

submit_button = Button(entrance_window, text="Submit", command=create_main_window).grid(row=1, column=0, columnspan=2)
entrance_window.mainloop()
```

Comment: You don't need the `entrance_window` in the `global main_window, entrance_window`. Also `place_entry` will always be `None`. Also what exactly are you trying to do with `f"{place_entry}"`?

Comment: I was only editing the OP’s code so that it doesn’t throw an error, I’m not sure of the reason for some of the script though.

Comment: When writing an answer please make sure that all possible bugs are fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Never used `global`. Don't use the wildcard `from tkinter import *`

The `Label` widget must be placed inside the `create_main_window() function` when you want to see the widget.

snippet:

```
import tkinter as tk


def create_main_window() -> None :   
    main_window = tk.Toplevel()
    tk.Label(main_window, text=f"{place_entry.get()}").pack()
     

entrance_window = tk.Tk()

first_text_label = tk.Label(entrance_window, text="you are in:").grid(row=0, column=0)

place_entry = tk.Entry(entrance_window)
place_entry.grid(row=0, column=1)

tk.Button(entrance_window, text="Submit", command=create_main_window).grid(row=1, column=0, columnspan=2)
 
entrance_window.mainloop()

if __name__=='__main__':
    create_main_window()
```

Screenshot:

[image]